# The input by user of a specific value, not exiting the program entirely

Tags: python, list

Trying to understand why the '-1' break execution is not taking place, when -1 is saved into the variable test1, the program just keeps running. Any pointers will be appreciated.

```
def example():
        exampleList  = []
        counter = 8
        while counter > len(exampleList):
                test1 = input('Please enter first name (or -1 to quit): ')
                test2 = input('Please enter last name: ')
                exampleList.append(test1)
                exampleList.append(test2)
                if test1 == '-1' or test2 == '-1':
                        break
                counter -= 1
        return exampleList

testing = example()
```

Comment: Are you saying the break is _never_ executed at all?  Or are you saying that it still asks for the last name after entering -1 for the first name, and you don't want it to do that?

Comment: What do you mean the program just keeps running? Do you mean to say that the next step is executed or that the counter actually gets reduced and the loop starts all over again? If the former, then it's working as expected by the code.

Comment: you want your test to quit directly after test1 if given -1?

Comment: When i change my code and check for '-1' after test1, my program still runs into my second function. My program does not exit, would it be helpful if i included my second function?

Comment: @Dante `break` only exits from the current, innermost loop; nothing else. If you want to kill the program outright, you can use `sys.exit()` from the `sys` module, or one of the various other similar functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
def example():
        exampleList  = []
        counter = 8
        while counter > len(exampleList):
                test1 = input('Please enter first name (or -1 to quit): ')
                if test1 == '-1':
                    break
                else:
                    test2 = input('Please enter last name: ')
                    if test2 == '-1':
                        break
                exampleList.append(test1)
                exampleList.append(test2)
                counter -= 1
        return exampleList
```

This will do your task.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue with this code in the function and made an if statment in the main line.

```
def example():
    exampleList  = []
    counter = 8
    while counter > len(exampleList):
            test1 = input('Please enter first name (or -1 to quit): ')
            if test1 == '-1':
               exampleList = 0
                break
            else:
                test2 = input('Please enter last name: ')
                if test2 == '-1':
                    break
            exampleList.append(test1)
            exampleList.append(test2)
            counter -= 1
    return exampleList
```

===================================

```
testing = example()
 if testing == 0:
     exit()
```